# PHP - Create global flag

Tags: php, global, flags

I am currently trying to find a way to create a flag (or variable) that can be accessed by all scripts. Meaning if I set the flag to true all scripts have that flag as true.

The point behind this that I am writing my own CSS, JS and HTML compressor. This script basically removes all unneccessary information from the code. Like unneccessary whitespace etc. The script is used with a call to `require_once`. It is working great but sometime I would like to globally disable it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you just looking for a constant? Or if not, how do those differ from your need?

Comment: `$GLOBALS['flag'] = true;` or define a variable within a global scope like `$flag = true;` and use/access it within the other function using global keyword `global $flag;`

Comment: You don't need to use the global keyword to access the $GLOBALS array. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: @Dean You missed the `or` word/operator in my comment.

Comment: Without knowing a great deal about your codes architecture, a `constant` is what you need.

Comment: @Wrikken I need a variable that can be accessed from every script.

Comment: @Hex: My apologies, I shouldn't SO early in the morning, without coffee! ;)

Comment: @Dean Or maybe I should have used uppercase for operator ;)

Comment: @BrainStone: you are saying something to me... that doesn't exclude using a constant... unless you say it should also be able to be _changed_ by any script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this but you might be better off creating a file like config.inc.php, including this within your compressor (e.g. compressor.php) and having a boolean flag within this config file like:

```
$compressorEnabled = true;
```

Then you include this in your compressor so that even when you have your require_once('compressor.php') in every one of your scripts, at the top of compressor.php you have something like:

```
if (!$compressorEnabled) {
    exit;
}
```

You could also use a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) rather than a variable, or do a couple of other things. Your main concern with including files this way in all scripts is preventing variable name collisions between the compressor script and whatever script you are including it into.

Comment: Thank you. I really haven't thought of this.